# CameraX: Make loading picture in gallery spontaneous

Tags: android, android-camera2, android-gallery, android-camerax, android-mediascanner

I am developing an android app based on CameraX. I have successfully designed the (image) preview part of the app with some loading animation and now have also added an functionality to view the picture in gallery along with other pictures taken by the app.

The issue here is sometimes the latest picture doesn't show up in the gallery, just as it shows up in the preview. I have used `MediaScanner.scanFiles` and it even runs the success callback. But it randomly takes a while to load the picture in gallery. Based on my observations, it loads the first picture quickly, but then takes a while to load an alternate picture (which again loads quickly). I tried scanning the same file twice, but it doesn't work as expected. Maybe I could scan the file, rename/(delete+create) it and again scan it, but would be too much of a workaround with no guarantee that the file would be immediately visible as soon as I open the gallery. Am I doing something wrong or missing out on something?

Here's the repository: https://github.com/MHShetty/grapheneos-camera

(Also, scanning the parent file tends to make it more spontaneous, but it isn't true always; it is slower with scanning the exact file on my device)

**Code that executes after the image gets saved**

```
                        Log.i(TAG, "Image saved successfully!");
                        final Uri imageUri = outputFileResults.getSavedUri();
                        if(imageUri!=null){
                            final String path = imageUri.getEncodedPath();
                            final Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
                            final File file = new File(path);

                            mActivity.getConfig().setLatestFile(file);

                            final String mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton()
                                    .getMimeTypeFromExtension(
                                            CamConfig.getExtension(new File(path))
                                    );

                            MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(
                                    mActivity,
                                    new String[]{file.getParent()},
                                    new String[]{mimeType},
                                    (path1, uri) -> {
                                        Log.d(TAG, "Image capture scanned" +
                                                " into media store: " + uri);

                                        mActivity.runOnUiThread(()-> {
                                            mActivity.getPreviewLoader()
                                                    .setVisibility(View.GONE);

                                            if (bm != null)
                                                mActivity.getImagePreview()
                                                        .setImageBitmap(bm);

                                        });
                                    }
                            );
                        }
```

**Code to open gallery**

```
    public void openGallery() {

        String mediaId = "";

        String[] projection = new String[] {
                MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME
        };

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                projection, null, null, null);

        if(cursor != null){
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                String name = cursor.getString((cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DISPLAY_NAME)));
                if(name.equals(config.getLatestMediaFile().getName())){
                    mediaId = cursor.getString((cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID)));
                    break;
                }
            }
            cursor.close();
        }

        Uri mediaUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

        if(!mediaId.equals("")){
            mediaUri = mediaUri.buildUpon()
                    .authority("media")
                    .appendPath(mediaId)
                    .build();
        }

        Log.d("TagInfo","Uri:  "+mediaUri);

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, mediaUri);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by gallery? ACTION_VIEW lets the user choose which app to use to display a file. Which app is opening for you?

Comment: `and it even runs the success callback.` Well then you get an uri for your file there. Use that uri. I see no reason to use a lot of code to query() the media strore to obtain... the same uri.

Comment: @blackapps It is the gallery app. It takes a while for it to show the latest image despite using `MediaConnection.scanFiles` as seen in the code snippets shared. (the occurrence and delay is almost random)

Comment: I want to be able to view other images in that folder at the same time along with the latest image. So that's why I can't use a specific file uri.

Comment: There is no 'the gallery app'. There can be a lot of apps on an Android device that can display images. It looks as if the user does not have to choose an app first. But you are not telling that.

Comment: `I want to be able to view other images in that folder`. Can be. But the uri you use for ACTION_VIEW is for one file. So what happens?

Comment: In my case, there was only one app that could do that, and that's the gallery app. So I didn't get an option.

Comment: Other images in that folder too become visible (on swipe). That's the expected behavior. But sometimes, the last/second last image appears instead of the latest one. So I always want the latest image to appear.

Comment: If the media store gives you an uri for a file then the file schould be there i think. Further: a 'gallery app' like Photos/Fotos will only show one image. No more. No swipes. Please install other image viewers.

Comment: It does show other files. I have shared the link to the repository in the answer. (https://github.com/MHShetty/grapheneos-camera). Please test it and let me know if I'm doing something wrong or missing out on something.

Comment: Sorry, i will not test your project.

Comment: That's completely fine  Thanks for your time.